# Create BAK of only schema and stored procedures without using DBCC CLONEDATABASE

Tags: sql-server

My first step of achieving this is to create a clone for only table schema and stored procedures.

But I came across an issue with `DBCC CLONEDATABASE`:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object "sys.sysowners" with unique index "nc1". The duplicate key value is "xxx"

This is the query I am using for cloning:

```
DBCC CLONEDATABASE ([DB_Full], [DB_SchemaAndSP])
WITH NO_STATISTICS, NO_QUERYSTORE;
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DB_SchemaAndSP] 
SET READ_WRITE
```

Because the solutions for `DBCC CLONEDATABASE` I have found online is to drop the user, I am currently looking for another solution to make a `.BAK` file for only table schema and stored procedures without needing the step above.

Comment: Do you have a clean out-of-the-box `model` database? One of the caveats if that you cannot use `DBCC CLONEDATABASE` if you have modified `model` at all. See: [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-clonedatabase-transact-sql#remarks).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I believe it is not clean neither do we have the clean instance of that `model`. There are multiple objects existing under `Security/Users`, this is exactly where the duplicate key the error message referring to.

Comment: Then the real solution is to clean it up. But one workaround is to backup/restore to another instance which has a fresh `model` database.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Sorry I did not quite able to relate to your point earlier. I have check the `model` database but how could I tell if this model is not modified?
I have tried to clone another database in this server as well as cloning a clone result, everything went fine except for this specific database.
Updated the error message on the question, I hope it helps describing the issue.
Thank you for the information.

Comment: @Charlieface We do not have enough storage for a copy of this database neither the data is permitted to transfer out of the machine. But if we cannot afford to clean the model, I will as well consider this workaround. Thank you for the suggestion to the workaround.

Comment: Easiest way to do that I think is to backup frommodel another instance (exact same version, edition and build number) and restore it using the normal `RESTORE` command